# Performing an inner join of data from Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have an Excel file. In the images below there are the two sheets it has.
I am trying to create a code in Python that takes into account the ISIN's that have "Weight" in image 2 (sheet 2) and then filter the data from those same ISIN in sheet 1.

### Spreadsheets

**Sheet 1**
[image: Image1/Sheet1]
**Sheet 2**
[image: Image2/Sheet2]

### Code

```py
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline 

pd.set_option("precision", 3)

portfolio = pd.read_excel("Track Record.xlsx", sheet_name="Track Record")

portfolio.set_index( "Date", inplace=True)

portfolio_t= portfolio.T

weights = pd.read_excel("Track Record.xlsx", sheet_name="Weights").dropna()

#inner_join= pd.merge(portfolio_t,weights, on='ISIN' , how='inner')
```

I was trying to solve my problem with a merge, but perhaps that is not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to merge on 'ISIN', it's not present in your transposed dataframe, look at Sheet1, it does not even mention such a name. You need to create a name 'ISIN' in the dataframe before performing the join.

Secondly, when you are trying to insert weights into your Sheet1 as a second row, it will ruin integrity of your data, so it's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to preserve you Date column, it will clearly be lost during your inner join, so you may want to do some other join, while if you don't want to preserve it and just want to keep a list of matched ISINs, then maybe you don't need the dataframes.

Generally you are on the right track, just take my remarks into a consideration, and it should work. Sorry, no code here because it's not very clear what is it that you need as a final thing.

Comment: I understand your answer. Basically what I want is to preserve the codes that are both in sheet 1 and sheet 2, taking into account the weights column from the last one.